# How can I mysqldump the contents of a few tables or just the schema?

Tags: mysql

Can you help me with the following:

- dump from the database just the contents of a few tables?
- dump just the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqldump -u username -p database [table] > file.sql

Use the --no-data option to dump just the schema.

mysqldump --no-data ...

Comment: nice and you can string a bunch of tables together with spaces